# Relationship function is not working in laravel

Tags: laravel

relationship function is not working of any type. i am creating 2 tables relationship of one to many but it is not working i have no idea at all about that i have follow tutorials and laravel documentation as well but all is vain please guide me thanks.

```html
//this is user model..

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','email','password','image','candidate_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
//

}



// and this is candidate model.


<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Candidate extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('app\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you should show your table schema.. so others can help you to solve the problem.

Comment: what could be the cases of this problem probably..?

Comment: naming of the table, foreign key not properly set, etc..

Comment: sir, i delete migration hardly has it any impact?

Comment: nope..just run migrate again..

Comment: models are singular start with capital latter, tables are same with plural, no syntax error, what could be the problem.?

Answer (score 1):

It shows your model User store candidate_id, so there is 1 Candidate many User..

in Candidate model (Table Name should be `candidates`)

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

in User model (Table Name should be `users`)

```
public function candidate()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Candidate::class);
}
```

Comment: is it necessary to write belongs to function?

Comment: oh! dude what i do? i have a candidate table too in my database actually i had created a migration of candidate name and for some reason i delete it hardly not from command now what i do it has any impact on my relation?

Answer (score 0):

All things were correct, I just call a single attribute of a second table instead of function. In Laravel we call function of related table not its attribute this is the mistake.